# Why am I getting 'Floating point exception: 8'

Tags: c, runtime-error, primes

I'm trying to calculate all the prime numbers from 0 - 100 and I'm getting a floating point exception, could anyone tell me why? (If it helps I'm using gcc)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int nums[100], i;

  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    nums[i] = i;

  int j,k,l,z;

  for(i=1;i<100;i++)
    for(j=2;j<100;j++)
      if((nums[i] % nums[j]) == 0)
       {
        nums[j] = 0;
       }

  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    if(nums[i] != 0)
      break;

  for(z=0;z<100;z++)
    {  
      for(k=i;k<100;k++)
       for(l = (k+2);l < 100;l++)
         if((nums[k] % nums[l]) == 0)
           nums[k] = 0;
    }

  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    if(nums[i] != 0)
      printf("%d,",nums[i]);

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad way to generate primes. Use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) instead

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's really hard to understand what your code is doing. But still

```
for(i=1;i<100;i++)
    for(j=2;j<100;j++)
        if((nums[i] % nums[j]) == 0)
        {
            nums[j] = 0;
        }
```

After this, many values of `nums` will be `0`.(You can print and check)

So, Later when you are doing

```
for(z=0;z<100;z++)
{  
  for(k=i;k<100;k++)
   for(l = (k+2);l < 100;l++)
     if((nums[k] % nums[l]) == 0) //Part where division by 0 occurs
       nums[k] = 0;
}
```

There will be a division by `0`, which is giving the `floating point exception`

**Edited**

Infact, there will be a `floating point exception` in the first two `for` loops only.. When `i=2` and `j=2`, `nums[2]` will get updated to value `0`. Then later when  for `i=4` and `j=2`. There will be a `division by 0`, because `num[2]` is already `0`,  thus causing the `floating point exception`

Comment: Thank, you very much! That helps a lot I will revisit it.

Comment: It will crash in the first code snippet for `i=4` and `j=2`, because `nums[2]` will be set to `0` when `i=2` and `j=2`. So the second code snippet will not be reached.